# strange java exception

Tags: java

I have tried execute this class as a java application and have got this following error .

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (classFileParser.cpp:3494), pid=4804, tid=5860
#  Error: ShouldNotReachHere()
#
# JRE version: 6.0_35-b10
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.10-b01 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# D:\HussainEclipse\GT_GoogleAPI_Android_Sept28\hs_err_pid4804.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

you can find my class file [here](http://www.sourcepod.com/tbbyzi61-11821)

any suggestion , what is going wrong ,

i haven't written this class , have just tried to understand , and it should bring me some desired output

also on an ending note
this class was importing edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.Configurations
but i could not find any jar for this , but i found a class definition so i created this class in my project which can be found [here](http://www.massapi.com/source/crawler4j-read-only/crawler4j/src/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/crawler/Configurations.java.html)

Comment: Better to know what is in hs_err_pid4804.log

Comment: You probably found a bug in the VM. What you got isn't an exception, but a VM crash (something that should not be possible to create just through Java code).

Comment: Please include the relevant part of your code in your question. *Every* external site will go sooner or later.

Comment: Can you run other classes without this crashing? Honestly, it looks like your JVM itself is malfunctioning and it's difficult to tell why from this.

Comment: Looks like [A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: Internal Error ; Error: ShouldNotReachHere()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6017431/851811).

Comment: @tzhechev : well the other files are executing properly , no JVm issue for any other class

Comment: @XaviLópez : yeah man , but i cant understand which part or why is it being caused

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312899/java-shouldnotreachhere-error

hope it helps

Comment: Next time put your class here. Don't expect people to click on external links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to execute Dalvik bytecode on a Oracle JVM. Although both are written with the same syntax, the bytecode is completely different. You need to recompile for Java.

Comment: well this is a part of the Android project and my other java classes wrok fine with it

Comment: You can't execute Android code on the JVM (even if some parts works). Use the emulator, you can add it as a plugin to eclipse (android plugin or android tools, I think).

Comment: The fact that the error is thrown from a JRE, and the project is supposed to be Android, should ring a bell. This is a configuration problem, I would say.

Comment: We don't see the structure of your project, but make sure the Android parts are executed on Dalvik VM, NOT Java VM. Just because Android code looks exactly like Java doesn't mean it is compatible with Java.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a JVM bug

Have a look at:
[A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: Internal Error ; Error: ShouldNotReachHere()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017431/a-fatal-error-has-been-detected-by-the-java-runtime-environment-internal-error)

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem within the JVM itself.

The JVM is just another program as it can have its own bugs/glitches/installation problems. This kind of error does not mean that you have an error in your Java program or that you did anything wrong (the same way than an internal error in MS Word does not mean that your document is wrong).

You should check the log file for more information, but I would just reinstall java/update to a newer version if possible as a first step.

Comment: ohk , will try this n let u guys knwo